# Dialogflow Firebase Realtime Database Getting Error: No responses defined for platform: Undefined yet method still goes through

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, foreach, dialogflow-es

I've been trying for a project I'm working on to develop a function for a Food chatbot. What I'm currently working on is to perform a method for a user to make a purchase of an order that is stored in firebase realtime database.

The method is set as the method for an actionMap and the actionMap is linked to an intent for knowing when to call the method and for retrieving the parameters.

My current method uses a simple check for a user's existence and status within the database before identifying the existence of the order they're trying to make a purchase for by its id by going through the user's reference path and doing a .forEach to check every order found and look at its parent folder name to check if it matches the user's order id. My code is as follows:

```
const MakePurchaseACTION = 'Make Purchase';


 function makePurchase(app){

let email = parameter.email;
let orderId = parameter.orderId;
var currDate = currDateGenerator();
var name = email.split(".com");

//Check if User exists first in database
var userRef = database.ref().child('user/' + name); 
        return userRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.exists()) { 
            let statusRetrieved = snapshot.child('Status').val();

            //Check if user's status in database is signed in.
            if (statusRetrieved == "Signed In") {
              var orderRef = database.ref().child('order/' + name);

              //Check the order table for the user.
                return orderRef.once('value').then(function(orderSnapshot){

                  let orderVal = orderSnapshot.val();
                  console.log(orderVal);

                  //Check through every child for the matching id.
                  orderSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    let orderIdFound = childSnapshot.key;
                    //let cost = childSnapshot.child('Cost').val();
                    console.log(orderIdFound);
                    if(orderId == orderIdFound) {
                      let eateryName = childSnapshot.child('Eatery').val();
                      let eateryLocation = childSnapshot.child('EateryLocation').val();
                      let deliveryAddress = childSnapshot.child('DeliveryAddress').val();
                      let orderItem = childSnapshot.child('OrderItem').val();
                      let quantity = childSnapshot.child('Quantity').val();
                      let cost = childSnapshot.child('Cost').val();

                       var purchaseRef = database.ref().child('purchase/' + name + "/" + currDate  + "/" + orderId);
                       purchaseRef.set({
                         "Eatery" : eateryName,
                         "EateryLocation" : eateryLocation,
                         "DeliveryAddress": deliveryAddress,
                         "OrderItem" : orderItem,
                         "Quantity": quantity,
                         "Cost": cost,
                         "DateCreated": currDate 
                       });

                      app.add("You have successfully purchased Order " + orderId);
                    } else {
                      app.add("There is no order with that id.");
                    }

                  });

                });
          } else {
            app.add("You need to be signed in before you can order!"); 
            }
          }
          else {
            app.add("Sorry pal you don't exist in the database.");
          }
        });
}



actionMap.set(MakePurchaseACTION, makePurchase);
```

After checking through some firebase logs

[Firebase Logs screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ZEb.png)

[Firebase Realtime Database Order Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvl9v.png)

I found that the method actually completes [Purchase table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iphyt.png) but my dialogflow returns with the stated error of:
Error: No responses defined for platform: undefined and displays "Not Available" back to the user. My question is how do I go about resolving this error?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you are calling `makePurchase()` and what the contents of the "unhandled rejection" were?

Comment: I have added in the adjustments its called as any usual method is via an action linked to an intent. As for the contents of unhandled rejection I've taken a new screenshot and updated it but as you will see it doesn't show any contents.